# Downgrade kubectl version to match minikube k8s version

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I started minikube with k8s version 1.5.2 and I would like to downgrade my kubectl so that it is also 1.5.2. Currently when I run  `kubectl version` I get:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5", GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T19:32:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I would like to use kubectl to fetch `PetSets` but in later versions this was updated to `StatefulSets` so I cannot use the commands with my current kubectl version

```
kubectl get petsets
the server doesn't have a resource type "petsets"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can just download the previous version binary and replace the one you have now.

Linux:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.5.2/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

macOS:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.5.2/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Windows:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.5.2/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
```

And add it to PATH.

If not follow instructions for other Operating Systems here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-via-curl

Comment: I'm on MAC. When I followed the instructions on the site. After completing them and running `kubectl version` I get the following message:
`-bash: /usr/local/bin/kubectl: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: I fixed the issue looks like I was downloading for linux instead of mac. Thanks!

Comment: Saving you mac users the extra 30 seconds
`curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.11.0/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl`

Update your version as needed.

Comment: @Skam: I don't think this would replace the current version which OP was asking originally.

Comment: My advice to all is, use the url provided in the k8s official doc (at this point in time is "https://dl.k8s.io") and follow the official doc hardcoding the version you want. Always be safe out there. ;)

Answer (score 5):

With APT you can install the exact version as well:

```
sudo apt install kubectl=1.17.2-00
```

Answer (score 2):

In my macOS, I was struggling, because I had multiple `kubectl` executables installed. First you need to remove the existing `kubectl` binaries. Do the following iteratively until it says `command not found: kubectl`.

```
which kubectl
sudo rm -f <path-from-above-command>
```

Next, follow the kubernetes official documentation to install your specific kubectl version.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/

1. If you want to install v1.18.0 for Apple M1 (see the above link for other OS versions)

`curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.18.0/bin/darwin/arm64/kubectl"`

2. Make the kubectl binary executable.

`chmod +x ./kubectl`

3. Move the kubectl binary to a file location on your system PATH.

`sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

`sudo chown root: /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

4. Test to ensure the version you installed is up-to-date:

`kubectl version --client`

Answer (score 1):

What helped me on Centos was running the following:

```
sudo yum downgrade kubeadm-1.16.9 kubernetes-cni-0.7.5 kubelet-1.16.9 kubectl-1.16.9
```

Then to disable updates forever, edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/Kubernetes.repo` and change the line with enabled to `enabled=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just manipulate the link

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/ shows 1.21.0
at https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.21.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe

The old 1.20.6 version is

https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.20.6/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe